# Blast output - program to count the number of hits

Tags: bioinformatics

I have to use the old version of Blast (not Blast+) to compare DNA sequences and I have to know the number of all hits. They are not given in the header and I have to know them for many many of blast outputs and its nearly impossible to count them (or to export them in excel). I think I probably have to write a 'Perl Script' and I did my best but I am not familiar with programming and it is not working. Furthermore I had a look on the internet and they are always comparing it to BIO Search. I have e code, which for me looks pretty good,but it also done a comparison with BIO Search, what I don't need/want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SearchIO;
```

## Usage information

```
die "Usage: $0 <BLAST-report-file> <number-of-top-hits> <output-file>\n", if (@ARGV != 3);

my ($infile,$numHits,$outfile) = @ARGV;
    print "Parsing the BLAST result ...";
    my $in = Bio::SearchIO->new(-format => 'blast', -file => $infile);
    open (OUT,">$outfile") or die "Cannot open $outfile: $!";

# print the header info for tab-deliminated columns
print OUT "query_name\tquery_length\taccession_number\tlength\tdescription\tE value\tbit score\tframe\tquery_start\t";
print OUT "query_end\thit_start\thit_end\tpositives\tidentical\n";

# extraction of information for each result recursively
while ( my $result = $in->next_result ) {
    # the name of the query sequence
    print OUT $result->query_name . "\t";

        # the length of the query sequence
        print OUT $result->query_length;

        # output "no hits found" if there is no hits
        if ( $result->num_hits == 0 ) {
      print OUT "\tNo hits found\n";
         } else {
      my $count = 0;

                # process each hit recursively
        while (my $hit = $result->next_hit) {
            print OUT "\t" if ($count > 0);
                            # get the accession numbers of the hits
       print OUT "\t" . $hit->accession . "\t";
                        # get the lengths of the hit sequences
                        print OUT $hit->length . "\t";
                            # get the description of the hit sequences
       print OUT $hit->description . "\t";
                        # get the E value of the hit
            print OUT $hit->significance . "\t";
                            #get the bit score of the hit
       print OUT $hit->bits . "\t";

                        my $hspcount = 0;

                        # process the top HSP for the top hit
            while (my $hsp = $hit->next_hsp) {
                            print OUT "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", if ($hspcount > 0);
                             # get the frame of the query sequence
        print OUT $hsp->query->frame . "\t";
                                # get the start and the end of the query sequence in the alignment
                print OUT $hsp->start('query') . "\t" . $hsp->end('query'). "\t";
                                # get the start and the end of the hit sequence in the alignment
                print OUT $hsp->start('hit') . "\t" . $hsp->end('hit') . "\t";
                                # get the similarity value
                printf OUT "%.1f" , ($hsp->frac_conserved * 100);
        print OUT "%\t";
                                    # get the identity value
        printf OUT "%.1f" , ($hsp->frac_identical * 100);
                    print OUT "%\n";
                                $hspcount++;
                            }
       $count++;

                        # flow control for the number of hits needed
            last if ($count == $numHits);
        }
        }
}
close OUT;
print " DONE!!!\n";
```

May someone help me, please. I need a program, which first tells me the header and then the number of hits. I am a little bit desperate and would be so happy if someone can help me. That would be so nice. Greetings Tina

Comment: Could you provide more info on how it's not working? I mean does it run but prints wrong output, or it won't run at all?

Comment: If your issue is related to your perl script then this is not on topic in biology-se. If you are interested in general procedure to get total number of hits you can see the above link.

Comment: Can you paste the output format?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The script i didn't write by myself, I just found it on the internet. I don't get any output, because it works with BioSearch (you have to download). But I think with little changes it could work...but i am not sure (4th line??). Maybe there is a easier way. I just wanted to ask here, if someone has an idea how it will work or how i can reach my aim, counting the hits. In the link you posted is written, that the hits are in the header, but there are not, in my case.

Comment: @Nina Paste the first 10 lines of your output. Without knowing how the output looks, we cannot help you

Comment: The scrip won't run because it has a missing package that it wants to use (use Bio::SearchIO;) so you either download it , or use a different script

Comment: What kind of output do you have? I would recommend the XML output, because it contains all the information and not only a part like the table output for example.  Use -outfmt 5 as parameter. Example: blast -db dbname -query path/to/query -out path/to/outfile -outfmt 5

Comment: @Nina The script you posted from the Internet has an absolute dependency on the Bio::SearchIO module of the BioPerl library. The script uses Perl's object-oriented syntax to parse the blast search output file that you specify on the command line. There are a few books that may be of help. Ian Korf and Mark Yandell have a book named Blast from O'Reilly, with working examples of Perl scripts for parsing blast reports. Jim Tisdall has two O'Reilly books, Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics AND Mastering Perl for Bioinfo. One of them has a chapter on parsing blast output (as I recall)

Answer (score 0):

This script, named blast2table.pl is from the code accompanying the Blast book by Korf & Yandell (there is a 3rd author whom I haven't met).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use vars qw($opt_p $opt_b $opt_e $opt_m $opt_n);
    getopts('p:b:e:m:n:');
    my $PERCENT = $opt_p ? $opt_p : 0;
my $BITS    = $opt_b ? $opt_b : 0;
    my $EXPECT  = $opt_e ? $opt_e : 1e30;
my $START   = $opt_m ? $opt_m : 0;
    my $END     = $opt_n ? $opt_n : 1e30;

my ($Query, $Sbjct);
my $HSP = "";
    while (<>) {
        if    (/^Query=\s+(\S+)/) {outputHSP(); $Query = $1}
        elsif (/^>(\S+)/)         {outputHSP(); $Sbjct = $1}
        elsif (/^ Score = /) {
            outputHSP();
            my @stat = ($_);
            while (<>) {
                last unless /\S/;
                push @stat, $_
            }
            my $stats = join("", @stat);
            my ($bits) = $stats =~ /(\d\S+) bits/;
            my ($expect) = $stats =~ /Expect\S* = ([\d\.\+\-e]+)/;
       $expect = "1$expect" if $expect =~ /^e/;
            my ($match, $total, $percent) = $stats =~ /Identities = (\d+)\/(\d+) \((\d+)%\)/;
            my $mismatch = $total - $match;

        $HSP = {bits => $bits, 
                    expect => $expect, 
                    mismatch => $mismatch, 
                    percent => $percent, 
                    q_begin => 0, 
                    q_end => 0, 
                    q_align => 0, 
                    s_begin => 0, 
                    s_end => 0, 
                    s_align => ""};
        }
        elsif (/^Query:\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)/) {
            $HSP->{q_begin}  = $1 unless $HSP->{q_begin};
            $HSP->{q_end}    = $3;
            $HSP->{q_align} .= $2;
        }
        elsif (/^Sbjct:\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)/) {
            $HSP->{s_begin}  = $1 unless $HSP->{s_begin};
            $HSP->{s_end}    = $3;
            $HSP->{s_align} .= $2;
    }
}
outputHSP();

sub outputHSP {
    return unless $HSP;
        return if $HSP->{percent}  < $PERCENT;
        return if $HSP->{bits}     < $BITS;
        return if $HSP->{expect}   > $EXPECT;
        return if ($HSP->{q_begin} < $START or $HSP->{q_end} < $START);
        return if ($HSP->{q_begin} > $END   or $HSP->{q_end} > $END);
        foreach my $field ('percent', 'q_align', 'mismatch', 's_align', 'q_begin', 'q_end', 's_begin', 's_end', 'expect', 'bits'){
        print "$field not defined\n" if not defined $HSP->{$field};
        }
        print join("\t", $Query, $Sbjct, $HSP->{percent}, length($HSP->{q_align}), $HSP->{mismatch}, countGaps($HSP->{q_align}) + countGaps($HSP->{s_align}), $HSP->{q_begin}, $HSP->{q_end}, $HSP->{s_begin}, $HSP->{s_end}, $HSP->{expect}, $HSP->{bits}), "\n";
    $HSP = "";
}

sub countGaps {
    my ($string) = @_;
        my $count = 0;
    while ($string =~ /\-+/g) {$count++}
        return $count;
}
```